# js replace some string with "\n"

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

if I have a string that I need to replace every `"^^"` in the text to break line but with no use for `<br>` because I am using `<texarea>` and the `<textarea>` will display the `<br>` as a text I wrote some code to do this but this doesn't work

```
var text="Hello ^^ World ^^ Break ^^ Line",
txt=text.replace(/^^/g,"\n");
```

who do i fix this?

tnx for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var text=" Hello ^^ World ^^ Break ^^ Line",
txt=text.replace(/\^\^/g,"\n");

console.log(txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your `^`, the correct regex would be `/\^\^/g`.

`^` otherwise means "starts with" (or "exclude", if it is the first character within square brackets).

Answer (score 1):

Another no-regex solution would be splitting up the string and join it again.

```js
var text="Hello ^^ World ^^ Break ^^ Line",
txt=text.split('^^').join('\n');

console.log(txt);
```

Keep in mind that this solution is not as fast as regular expression solutions but it will work fine.